# Stopped sequence with Uniform distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution, order-statistics

let $U_1,U_2,...$ be independent uniform $U(0,1)$ random variables, and let $N$ be the first $n\ge2$ such that $U_n>U_{n-1}$

I'm trying to find $P(U_1\le{u} \text{ and }N=n)$ for  $0\le u\le 1$ and $n\ge2$

I'm not sure what topic covers this problem (order statistics?) so I'm unable to work on it with the little information I have.

Comment: I've suggested changing the title to: Stopped sequence (rather than order statistics), as the linkage to order statistics does not seem primary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a neat problem, with a neat solution. The sequence stops at $N$ terms as soon as the $n^{\text{th}}$ value is larger than the preceding $(n-1)^{\text{th}}$ term.  The number of terms $N=n$ is thus also a random variable with pmf:

- $P(N=2) \; = \; P(U_2>U_1) = \frac12$
- $P(N=3) \; = \; P(U_2 < U_1) \; \centerdot \; P(U_3 > U_2  \; \mid \; U_2 < U_1) = \frac12 \centerdot \frac23$
- $P(N=4) \; = \; P(U_2 < U_1) \; \centerdot \; P(U_3 < U_2  \; \mid \; U_2 < U_1) \; \centerdot \; P(U_4 > U_3  \; \mid \; U_3 < U_2 < U_1) \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad = \frac12 \centerdot \frac13 \centerdot \frac34$
- $\dots$ and by induction, the general solution for the pmf of $N$ is:

$$P(N=n) \; = \; \frac{n-1}{n!}  \quad \quad   \text{ for } n \ge 2$$

To derive the probabilities above intuitively, consider for instance:

$$P(U_4 > U_3  \; \mid \; U_3 < U_2 < U_1)$$

Since the $U_i$ are iid and Uniform, the condition ${U_3 < U_2 < U_1}$ breaks the unit line into 4 equally likely segments:

[image]

and the probability that $U_4$ will fall into the first segment is thus $\frac14$ (or $\frac34$ that it will land in any of the other 3 segments.

Here is a plot of the pmf $P(N=n)$:

[image]

The cdf $P(N \le n)$, for integer valued $n$ is:  $\quad 1 - \frac{1}{n!}$

Answer (score 0):

So that's the probability that $u\ge U_1\ge U_2\ge\cdots \ge U_{N-1}<U_N$.
That will be $P_{N-1}(u)-P_{N}(u)$ where $P_N(u)$ is the probability that
$u\ge U_1\ge U_2\ge\cdots\ge U_N$. There's surely a simple relation between $P_N(u)$ and the probability that all of $U_1,\ldots,U_N$ are $\le u$?

Comment: Vice versa, $P_{n-1}(u)-P_n(u)$. Otherwise difference is negative.